Typescript type to only include members with decorator?
I am messing around with an Angular project. Angular has a property decorator called Input, and I have run into a case where I would like to create a conditional type that excludes all members from a component without the @Input decorator.
So for a class like
export class MyComponent {
    @Input
    public includeMe: string;

    public excludeMe: string;

}

I would like a Typescript Type such that
type MyTypedComponent = MyType
returns a type that only includes members decorated with @Input (In this case includeMe)
Is this possible? And how?
If its not possible with types, but with function generics for example, I am in no way picky :)

It's impossible. Decorators don't mutate types; the resulting MyComponent type is identical to what it would be without the decorator, so the type system has no way to tell the difference. Your question referring to "function generics" confuses me; I can't tell what sorts of things you'd consider in scope. There might be some runtime way to tell which properties are decorated, but that's not what you seem to be asking, and it depends on your use case and whatever @Input is (the q isn't tagged "angular", so this isn't a [mre]). Please [edit] to clarify.

It is not possible with typescript directly. Maybe you can generate the types you want using ts-morph?
